# How to remove the border of the cascade menu in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, menu

I'm new to Tkinter and while experimenting with it, I hit a problem, The color of the cascade menu could be changed easily but the border cannot be removed. Is there a cross platform way to do it? I want the border to be either of the same color as background or be removed. [Here's the snippet][1]

```py
from tkinter import*  
root= Tk()  
root.configure(bg="#20232A")  
root.geometry("500x500")  
menubar = Menu(root)  

File= Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0, bg="#20232A", fg="#ffffff", bd=0)  
File.add_command(label="New File                       Ctrl+N")  
File.add_command(label="New Window          Ctrl+Shift+N")  
File.add_separator()  
File.add_command(label="Recent           ")  
File.add_command(label="Open                            Ctrl+O")  
File.add_separator()  
File.add_command(label="Save                              Ctrl+S")  
File.add_command(label="Save as                    Ctrl+Shift+S")  
File.add_separator()  
File.add_command(label="Quit                             Alt+F4")  
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=File)  


root.config(menu=menubar)  
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please add your code so we can check what's wrong or whar are you trying: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: ***How to remove the border of the cascade menu***:  Does this answer your question? [a-customized-menu-bar-without-using-the-widget-tk-menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60730049)

Comment: @stovfl:  Yes, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the argument `bd = 0` wich should set border's size to 0 while making your cascade menu.

Comment: I've tried using bd = 0, but it doesn't work. BTW I'm on windows.

Comment: @Akr_26: On *Windows*, Tcl/tk don't support this.

Comment: Then maybe with the ```highlightthickness``` parameter ?

Comment: @TheMachinist: Using `highlightthickness` gives an error. Looks like it's not a valid parameter for menu widgets.

Comment: Oh then I don't know, maybe if you search for more parameters, else I think it's somewhere else...