# Customizing Menu widget in Python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm building a Tkinter application and it's almost complete except for some aesthetic tweaks. I managed to customize almost all elements except for this `Menu` widget. In the first image below, you can see `font`, `bg` arguments doesn't do anything, although the same arguments work in the sub-menu. (see the second image)

Here's the code snippet:

```
root = Tk(className=r" Movie and TV Shows Recommendation System")  # creates a window in which we work our gui
root.geometry('960x720')  # width x height
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)  # restricts window size

# 'font', 'bg' arguments doesn't do anything here (see first image)
menu = Menu(root, font='Courier 12', bg='black')

# although it works here (see second image)
helpMenu = Menu(menu, tearoff=0, font='Courier 11', bg='yellow', activebackground='black', activeforeground='white')

menu.add_cascade(label='Menu', menu=helpMenu)
helpMenu.add_command(label='How it Works?', command=open_popup)
helpMenu.add_separator()
helpMenu.add_command(label='See project in GitHub...', command=lambda: webbrowser.open_new("someurl.com"))
helpMenu.add_separator()
helpMenu.add_command(label='Donate via PayPal...', command=lambda: webbrowser.open_new("https://someurl.com"))
helpMenu.add_separator()
helpMenu.add_command(label='Exit', command=root.destroy)
```

[image: See Image:]

[image: same arguments works in the sub-menu]

I also tried `menu.config(bg='black')`, didn't do the trick. If you know any other way to customize this, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: You can't do that, read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49089262/12631229

Comment: @ManishPushpam I figured, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Here is a "workaround" to customize the Menu: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60762140/11502612